# Tuning randomForest cutoffs with MLR package

Tags: r, mlr

I've been exploring the marvelous `mlr` package with the titanic [data set](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data).  My problem is implementing a random forest.  More specifically, I'd like to tune the `cutoff` (i.e. the threshold which assigns leafs which are not pure to a given class).  The problem is that the `cutoff` argument takes two values, however, I can only figure out hyperparameter turning in `mlr` for a single value .

The code:

```
library(mlr)
library(dplyr)

dTrain <- read.csv('path/to/data/')

#Defining the Task
trainTask <- makeClassifTask(data = dTrain %>% 
                           select(-Name, -Ticket, -Cabin) %>% 
                           filter(complete.cases(.)), 
                         target = "Survived", 
                         id = "PassengerId")

#Defining Learning
rfLRN <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest")

#Defining the Parameter Space
ps <- makeParamSet(
 makeDiscreteParam("cutoff", values = list(c(.5,.5), c(.75,.25)))
)
```

This is were the problem lies, `cutoff` needs two values, however, I'm not sure how to pass these two values.  The above attempt is wrong.  I've attempted several other parameter makers, i.e.  `makeDiscreteVectorParam`, etc.... but to no avail.  Any tips?

If instead I attempt to tune a parameter like `mtry` (i.e the number of features to select from at a given split) everything works fine.

```
#Defining the Hyperparameter Space
ps = makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("mtry", values = c(2,3,4,5))
)

#Defining Resampling
cvTask <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters=5L)

#Defining Search
search <-  makeTuneControlGrid()

#Tune!
tune <- tuneParams(learner = rfLRN
                 ,task = trainTask
                 ,resampling = cvTask
                 ,measures = list(acc)
                 ,par.set = ps
                 ,control = search
                 ,show.info = TRUE)
```

Comment: For those with a similar problem, a better approach is to use `makeNumericParam("cutoff", lower = .2, upper = .8, trafo = function(x) c(x, 1-x))` instead of   `makeDiscreteParam("cutoff", values = list(a=c(.50,.50), b=c(.75,.25))`.  Much less coding to get an exhaustive search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to assign names to these classification cutoffs, e.g.:

```
#Defining the Parameter Space
ps <- makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("cutoff", values = list(
    a=c(.50,.50),
    b=c(.75,.25)))
)
```

Output:

```
> tune <- tuneParams(learner = rfLRN
+                    ,task = trainTask
+                    ,resampling = cvTask
+                    ,measures = list(acc)
+                    ,par.set = ps
+                    ,control = search
+                    ,show.info = TRUE)
[Tune] Started tuning learner classif.randomForest for parameter set:
           Type len Def Constr Req Tunable Trafo
cutoff discrete   -   -    a,b   -    TRUE     -
With control class: TuneControlGrid
Imputation value: -0
[Tune-x] 1: cutoff=a
[Tune-y] 1: acc.test.mean=0.828; time: 0.0 min
[Tune-x] 2: cutoff=b
[Tune-y] 2: acc.test.mean=0.776; time: 0.0 min
[Tune] Result: cutoff=a : acc.test.mean=0.828
```